# Getting all files that have been modified on a specific date

Tags: command-line, find, date

Is it possible to find all `php` files within a certain directory that have been modified on a certain date

I'm using

```
find /var/www/html/dir/ -mtime -28 | grep '\.php'
```

to get files modified within the last 28 days, but I only need files that have been modified on the following date: `2011-02-08`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On recent versions of `find` (e.g. GNU 4.4.0) you can use the `-newermt` option. For example, to find all files that have been modified on the 2011-02-08

```
$ find /var/www/html/dir/ -type f -name "*.php" -newermt 2011-02-08 ! -newermt 2011-02-09
```

Also note that you don't need to pipe into grep to find php files because find can do that for you in the `-name` option.

Take a look at this SO answer for more suggestions: [How to use 'find' to search for files created on a specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date)

Answer (score 7):

Annoyingly, there isn't any direct way with standard `find`. Recent versions of `find` on GNU systems (e.g. non-embedded Linux, Cygwin) and some *BSDs have [options such as `-newermt` to compare a file date with a spelled-out date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/getting-all-files-that-have-been-modified-on-a-specific-date/8752#8752).

With standard `find`, all you can do is compare the file date with the current date (`-mtime`) or with a fixed file. The current date is usually not useful in this case (it counts back from the time you run the `find` command, whereas most applications require a calendar date). That leaves you with the kludge of creating temporary files to define a range.

```
touch -t 201103070000 start.tmp
touch -t 201103080000 stop.tmp
find . -newer start.tmp \! -newer stop.tmp -print
rm start.tmp stop.tmp
```

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh` you could use the [function `age`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Calendar-Function-System.html#Glob-qualifiers) to print only the names of files that have been modified on a certain date:

```
autoload age
print -rl -- *.php(.e:age 2011/02/08:)
```

or, if you want to search recursively:

```
autoload age
print -rl -- **/*.php(.e:age 2011/02/08:)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have *almost* the right command already, for versions of `find` that won't let you use dates:

```
find /var/www/html/dir/ -mtime 27 | grep '\.php'
```

In general, for `find` -*n* means *fewer than*, *n* means *equal*, +*n* means "more than".  Traditional `find` has some exceptions, but GNU `find` and other newer versions such as on BSD/Mac OS X corrected those.  (Keep this in mind if you ever find yourself on a Solaris or other commercial Unix system.)

Answer (score -6):

In most cases I use basic commands:

```
ls -l | grep 2017 | grep Apr\ 11
ls -l | grep 2017 | grep Apr\ 1\
```

Note: add space at the end of second command. Files, mixed with directories, are not problem in case of interactive search on command line.

Comment: Will probably fail for files that have names that contain either `2017` or `Apr 4` as substrings. Also, this will output a lot more than just filenames.

Comment: Is it not an answer of original question? Simple and basic

Comment: The issue is that it's too simplistic. Any file can contain the strings `2017` and `Apr 11` in their names without having been created or modified on that date. Your commands would pick these up. You also, as I pointed out in my last comment, get more data out of this than just the filename. So no, this does not answer the question.

Comment: You are right about "file can contain the strings 2017 and Apr 11 in their names". But why do you decide it is a problem? I'm (php) programmer on Windows desktop and have basic knowledge of linux. Why do you force me browse internet and search command, which I forgot for a years? ls and grep, basic linux commands, fully satisfy me in 99% cases. Do I be forced waste my time by nobody wishes. I do use ls | grep and will use in the future in most cases. Read carefully original question and thing about author needs.

Comment: Ok, let's do a test: run the command `touch 'notes from 2017 Apr 1.txt'`. This file is _clearly_ not last modified of April the 1st, 2017 but today. The original questions asks about finding (PHP) files that were modified on a particular date. If the date is April 1st, 2017, then this new file should _not_ turn up in the response. Also, I do not force you to do anything, but I do care about the quality and correctness of answers on this site.

Comment: On a Linux system, try: `touch -d "April 11 2017" "a file with"$'\n'"a newline"` and then try your approach: `ls -l | grep 2017 | grep Apr\ 11`. You will see that only the first part of the file name will be returned, and you will therefore not get the right name.

Comment: As others said, grepping the output of `ls` is prone to false-positives, including not only the date but also the filename, user, and group. I would also point out two things: this is not an answer to the question *as written* because the question asks for files modified on a specific date: 2011-02-08, and you've given two dates in April of 2017 in your answer. Beyond that particularity, the question was asked on 2011-03-07 about a 2011-02-08 date; `ls` will not report the *year* of a file until it is 6 months old, meaning that grepping for the year will *never* succeed for "recent" files.