# Command works fine but fails when executed remotely over ssh

Tags: ssh, date, remote, xargs

The below command works fine of remote AiX server when run on the server.

```
ls -ltr /tmp/*.pid  | grep "$(date '+%b %e')"
```

Output:

```
-rwx-rwx-rw-- ........ Oct 1 /tmp/new.pid

echo $?
0
```

I wish to run the above command using `ssh` but it fails. See output below:

```
ssh user@10.0.0.9 -C 'ls -ltr /tmp/*.pid  | grep "$(date "'"+%b %e"'")"'

echo $?
1
```

Note: The command gets from `"$(date '+%b %e')"` to `grep "$(date "'"+%b %e"'")"` by ansible automation.

```
-name: Chek is pid file was modified today
 raw: "ls -ltr /tmp/{{ another_folder }}/*.pid  | grep \"$(date '+%b %e')\""
 register: pidfiledet
```

Can you please suggest how can I address this issue and get the command to run remotely as well ?

Update: I ran the commands suggested by users in the answer and comment sections however, the ssh fails. Below is the failing ssh output in debug mode for the answers that were suggested.

```
$ ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/app/mysshkeys/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="tbaadm"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPath=/home/targetuser/.ansible/cp/f623d39604 -tt 10.9.9.12 'ls -ltr /tmp/prjfolder/bin/*.pid | grep "$(date +%b\ %e)"'
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 73756
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 1
Shared connection to 10.9.9.12 closed.
```

Note, the command passed using ssh above works fine when executed locally on the target host!!

Comment: Try `ssh user@10.0.0.9 -C 'ls -ltr /tmp/*.pid  | grep "$(date '\''+%b %e'\'')"'`

Comment: What does "_it fails_" actually mean? What did you expect? What happened? What didn't happen? Why do you think this is incorrect behaviour? Note that the status doesn't necessarily mean the command has failed; it could mean that the `grep` didn't match

Comment: Experience suggests that this is one of those questions where lots of people are going to go all around the houses trying to get the questioner to explain, and it will eventually transpire that the file had been deleted, or that it was now the 2nd of October in the questioner's timezone, or some such.

Comment: @user414777 `grep "$(date '+%b %e')"` get translated to `grep "$(date "'"+%b %e"'")"` by ansible automation so that is not in my control. However, other solutions is what I'm looking for.

Comment: "translated ... by ansible automation" would be a key part of the question that is not in the question.

Comment: @kbulgrien updated the same in the original question.

Comment: Does it help if you remove quoting mess by the date command argument along the lines of `ls -ltr /tmp/*.pid  | grep "$(date +%b\ %e)"`?

Comment: @kbulgrien seems to work !! but I will only be able to confirm in the next 3 hours...

Comment: `grep` returns no output and the exit status `1` after it matches nothing. Review `ssh user@10.0.0.9 -C 'ls -ltr /tmp/*.pid'` and `ssh user@10.0.0.9 -C 'date "+%b %e"'`. Are they what you expect? If not, check if this applies: [Time Zone is getting different over `ssh command` & normal `ssh`](https://superuser.com/q/814882/432690). In one timezone the timestamp may still be "today", in another it may be "yesterday". Parsing `ls` is [bad idea in general](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Parsing `ls` to match mtime is [not the right thing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/578400/108618).

Comment: You may have some success in getting the dated metadata of the file in question with `stat` rather than `ls`.  Unless you want a Mk. I Eyeball to look at a list of filenames, `ls` is almost always the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I have shared updated the original question with the failing ssh output in debug mode. None of the suggestions worked @kbulgrien. Considering this has to do with ansible as well i'm planning to post afresh on stackoverflow.

Comment: Similar error at least in the first error log:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51675831/ansible-stops-connecting-to-the-host-via-ssh/51679353

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with `ansible`, but since it appears that `ansible` is in the mix, and the problem is that another process translates the command in a way that breaks quoting, perhaps eliminating the quoting in that part of the command may help.

It may be worth trying a base command something like this:

```
ls -ltr /tmp/*.pid  | grep "$(date +%b\ %e)"
```

The question remains as to whether the translator might break that too.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained what you mean by "*it fails*" so I can only guess

1. Rather than packaging up the entire pipeline to run remotely, you could run the necessary part remotely and the remainder locally

   ```
    ssh user@10.0.0.9 -C 'ls -ltr /tmp/*.pid' | grep "$(date '+%b %e')"
   ```

   The biggest advantage of this (in my opinion, of course) is that is keeps quoting simple and straightforward. You have to balance that against the amount of data traversing the network pipe and possible differences in timezone (in the instance of `date`)

If you know the timezone of the source machine you can instruct `date` to use it even when running locally, forr example

```
    ssh user@10.0.0.9 -C 'ls -ltr /tmp/*.pid' | grep "$(TZ=Europe/Paris date '+%b %e')"
```

1. Bear in mind that your exit status code could simply mean that `grep` failed to match anything. I don't know if in your case that in itself is an error, but it's normal behaviour for `ssh` to return its command's final exit status

   ```
    ssh remoteHost true; echo SS=$?
    SS=0
    ssh remoteHost false; echo SS=$?
    SS=1
   ```

Comment: This is BAD. The local and the remote user can be in different time zones. Besides, it's not answering the question.

Comment: Timezone difference is actually the reason ... This does not answer my query ... agree with @user414777. ssh command is successful but the way i'm checking for success and failure is by `echo $?`

Comment: @user414777 good catch. I always use UTC and simply forgot others don't. Answer amended

Comment: @Ashar I don't understand what you mean. All my examples return status through `$?`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Ansible, but here is the working ssh command:

```
ssh user@10.0.0.9 'touch /tmp/test.pid; ls -ld /tmp/*.pid | grep -- "$(date "+%b %d")"'
```

Note: even if you have `GNU!binutils` installed on your AIX-server, commands executed via ssh use a minimal PATH that doesn't include `/opt/freeware/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, so use full-path if you want to use `GNU!ls`:

```
ssh user@10.0.0.9 'touch /tmp/test.pid; /usr/local/bin/ls -ld /tmp/*.pid | grep -- "$(date "+%b %e")"'
```

Edit:
Regarding `date` %-sequences: `AIX!ls` is compatible with `%d`, GNU!ls with `%e`.

Comment: Now try `%e` as in the question.  Enjoy counting the number of spaces.  Then enjoy adding Ansible, locale-specific date formats in `ls`, and non-login non-interactive shells into the mix.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP Very true, an actual solution should be based on standardized locale, standardized timezone, and using `find` utility. (Edited the answer to press the difference between %d and %e) Regarding Ansible: I don't know it, but heard that it worth learning it, as expert Ansible-users can solve the problems that are caused by using Ansible.